# class gets unset when including smarty and facebook php

Tags: php, facebook, class, oop, smarty

I don't understand this:

I use the `__autoload` feature in php and this works:

```
include_once '../sys/core/init.inc.php';

$Intro = new Intro(); 
echo $Intro->ip(); 
exit();
```

`init.inc.php` loads the Intro class and the `ip()` function prints out the ip.

But this does not work

```
include_once '../sys/core/init.inc.php';

/*
 * Smarty template engine
 */

include_once '../sys/core/smarty/Smarty.class.php'; 

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->caching = false;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 86400; // 24 timer

/*
 * gettext translation
 */

if( ! defined('PROJECT_DIR')){ define('PROJECT_DIR', realpath('/var/www/v3/')); }   
if( ! defined('LOCALE_DIR')){ define('LOCALE_DIR', PROJECT_DIR .'/sys/locale'); }
if( ! defined('DEFAULT_LOCALE')){ define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'no_NO'); }
include_once('../sys/core/gettext/gettext.inc');
$encoding = 'utf-8';
$locale = (isset($_COOKIE['lang']))? $_COOKIE['lang'] : DEFAULT_LOCALE;
T_setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
$domain = 'messages';
T_bindtextdomain($domain, LOCALE_DIR);
T_bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $encoding);
T_textdomain($domain);

/*
 * facebook
 */

include_once '../sys/core/facebook/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true,
)); 

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me'); // me?fields=email
    $email = $facebook->api('me?fields=email');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array('req_perms' => 'email, publish_stream')
    );
}

$Intro = new Intro(); 
echo $Intro->ip(); 
exit();
```

Now I get `Fatal error: Class 'Intro' not found in ... on line 92`

I don't understand this because the only code I have added is required includes for `facebook`, `gettext` and `smarty`. Before the includes I can call classes, but not after I have added the includes. This makes no sense to be. Can someone explain.

Comment: Is it finding the file that contains the Intro class? Are the include statements throwing any PHP Warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call your class directly after the include:

```
include_once '../sys/core/init.inc.php';

$Intro = new Intro(); 

/*
 * Smarty template engine
 */

include_once '../sys/core/smarty/Smarty.class.php'; 

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->caching = false;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 86400; // 24 timer

/*
 * gettext translation
 */

if( ! defined('PROJECT_DIR')){ define('PROJECT_DIR', realpath('/var/www/v3/')); }   
if( ! defined('LOCALE_DIR')){ define('LOCALE_DIR', PROJECT_DIR .'/sys/locale'); }
if( ! defined('DEFAULT_LOCALE')){ define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'no_NO'); }
include_once('../sys/core/gettext/gettext.inc');
$encoding = 'utf-8';
$locale = (isset($_COOKIE['lang']))? $_COOKIE['lang'] : DEFAULT_LOCALE;
T_setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
$domain = 'messages';
T_bindtextdomain($domain, LOCALE_DIR);
T_bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $encoding);
T_textdomain($domain);

/*
 * facebook
 */

include_once '../sys/core/facebook/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  'cookie' => true,
)); 

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me'); // me?fields=email
    $email = $facebook->api('me?fields=email');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array('req_perms' => 'email, publish_stream')
    );
}

echo $Intro->ip(); 
exit();
```

Shouldn't work either, but may be a good start for debugging. However, it might be useful to post your Intro class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple guess, i haven't really used these librairies (except for Smarty) in a while, but it might be that one of the libraries (Facebook or Gettext) also define a __autoload function that gets called instead of your own.

You can display what is used by PHP for autoloading by calling `var_dump(spl_autoload_functions())`.

Also, your autoload function might be using a constant or variable getting overwritten by the includes.